# Is unmounted USB drive more durable than mounted one?

Tags: mount, usb, backup

I'm thinking of running a file server on Raspberry Pi with two USB flash memories. Should I `mount` and `umount` every time I execute the backup? I mean, is the `umount`ed USB more durable than `mount`ed USB (in terms of power, temperature, etc...)?

Detailed situation:

- I use `rsync` to backup files.
- Since I use a script, `umount` and `mount` isn't troublesome.
- Total file size is just around 5GB and the actual size transferred is from 100KB to 100MB.
- On average, I execute the backup 2-3 times a day.
- The server does never shutdown.
- The USBs are used only for the backup and have the same contents like mirroring.
- I understand the fragility of USB memory. (Actually I backup files to many places. The file server I'm planning to make is just a sub-system.)

I would like to take the safer option. I'm glad to get any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be safe to keep the USB stick mounted. As there is no other activity on the USB stick, there should not be many writes while it is not in use.

On the other hand, the mount / umount in the script doesn't hurt you, so you don't lose anything if you unmount. Plus you are protected against accidental overwrites.